# Using external values as conditions in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I’m building an application which needs to aggregate measures coming from a series of sensors deployed in different areas. The measures are ingested using Kafka. I'm new to Flink but I already figured out how to aggregate events with a window and send them in a sink. However I also need to compare the aggregate values per area with thresholds (also per area) coming from an external db (in my case Postgres). These thresholds can also be updated over time or added whenever a new area is created. Any suggestion?
Thanks
euks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stream in the thresholds from Postgres, you could set up a Table source connected to Postgres via debezium. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRIQqgI1gLA is a good resource for learning about that. Or you could do a [lookup join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join), with [caching](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#lookup-cache) (if that's desirable).

Once you've got the thresholds streaming in, then you can, for example, model the changelog stream of thresholds as a versioned table, and use a [temporal join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#temporal-joins) to combine it with the primary stream.

If for some reason that doesn't get you what you want, you could convert the dynamic tables to DataStreams, and use a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` to implement a lower-level solution (more work but more flexible). Or if there is no shared key between the two data sources, you can instead [broadcast](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) the thresholds.

Comment: Thank you I’ll try debezium, it looks very interesting. Given that the stream of thresholds changes very infrequently (the measures are taken every hour but the thresholds are stored when an area to monitor is created and are rarely updated) what  is the best way to combine the streams?